# how to get elastic search java api 5.0 detail changes log from es2.3.4

Tags: elasticsearch

elastic search have publish lastest java api ,After much search,i failed to find the detail changes log. 
I have got a open-source elastic-helper code to synchronize mysql with es.when i used the lastest java api(elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar),i got a lot of error because of the changes of API. 
I want to find useful document to refer to.

Comment: All the details can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_java_api_changes.html)

Comment: I have check the document,it doesn't refer to details like “import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLogger” “import org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.ChannelBufferBytesReference” which become error since i used the eslaticsearch-5.0.1。（last version i used is elasticsearch-2.3.4）

Comment: Well, then, you should be more precise about what you need.

Comment: ESLogger [has been removed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20235)